# Confusion on virtual functions declaration and definition

Tags: c++, c++11, coding-style, virtual-functions

These are some concern I have since when I understand how to use and what to use virtual functions for.

First, online, I've seen many styles for declaring virtual functions. While `virtual` is *always* (obviously) written in the base class's virtual function declaration, the derived class's declaration is sometimes declared with `virtual`, sometimes with `override`, sometimes with both, sometimes with neither. What is the correct style?

Second, if I have a virtual function in the base class, but in one of the derived classes I don't want to make that function usable, how do I do it?

Third, do I have to put `virtual` in the function definition (in the .cpp file)?

Comment: opinion based answer!!

Answer (score 1):

1. virtual in base class override in derived class
2. declare it private or deleted
3. no, you dont. only in header